# Training Yolact on Google Colab+ without timing out

Tags: computer-vision, google-colaboratory, image-segmentation, yolo, dataset

I want to train Yolact on a custom dataset using Google Colab+.
Is it possible to train on Colab+ or does it time out to easily?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can train your model on Colab+. The problem is that Colab has a relatively short lifecycle compared with other cloud platforms such as AWS SageMaker or Google Cloud. I run the code below to extend a bit more such time.

```
%%javascript
function ClickConnect(){
console.log("Working");
document.querySelector("colab-toolbar-button#connect").click()
}setInterval(ClickConnect,50000)
```